# I have set a me@example.com to Google Apps/Gmail. How can I set a you@example.com?

Tags: google, email, google-workspace, gmail

Suppose that my domain is `example.com`. I have set as a primary email address at Google Apps/Gmail this address `me@example.com`.

However I want to check the email of `info@example.com` through Google Apps.

I know I can add it through Gmail->Settings->Accounts->Send mail as/Check mail using POP3.

Is there another way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to acheive this with Google Apps (standard or enterprise):

1. **Create a '[nickname](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182527)'** (otherwise known as a email alias). This will allow any email sent to `info@example.com` to appear in the inbox of `me@example.com`.
2. **Create a [group](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33343)** (otherwise known as a distribution list). This will allow email sent to `info@example.com` to appear in the inboxes of `me@example.com`, `you@example.com`, or `them@example.com`. You can have anything from 1 to 1000 users in a group and if you'll be adding other users later this may be the best approach.
3. **Create a [separate account](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=179832)** and [check it via pop3](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=21289) with your existing `me@example.com` account.

**IMHO** if its only you accessing this extra account then **1** is your best option, if you think one or two other users might need to access it together now or in the future then go for option **2**.

Option 3 is best for email accounts **not** managed by Google Apps.

Comment: 4. Create a separate account and make it forward for faster delivery

Comment: @SLaks how would this achieve faster delivery when you could do 1 or 2 and not make it run through another gateway - with those options you'd get the message much faster than my 3 or your 4.

Comment: I meant faster delivery than your `3`.  (although I can't imagine that forwarding is more than a second slower than `1` or `2`)

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming you have a Google Apps for Business account**

You need to add a user account:

- Goto [this link](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html)
- Login to 'Domain Management'

Or, if you're already logged in under your Apps account...

Goto:

```
https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/[your_site]/Dashboard
```

Under the 'Organizations and Users' menu you can add more accounts.

*Note: I'm assuming that you already have gmail enabled for your domain so an email account will automatically be added/enabled for new users. If not, you can enable it under the 'Setup' section of the 'Dashboard'.*